# Creating New Build Configuration Results in Header Not Found Error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode8

In Xcode I have created a new `Staging` build configuration. I duplicated the `Release` configuration to make it. Both the `Release` and the `Debug` configurations build just fine. When I select the `Staging` config I end up with header issues. **I have checked in the build settings to ensure that all three configs have the same header search paths.**

As an important side note, the issues are popping up between a couple libraries I have that are referencing each other.

To be specific I am using a library called CodePush that references the React library like this:

```
#if __has_include("RCTEventEmitter.h")
    #import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
#else
    #import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
#endif
```

Which the `RCTEventEmitter.h` file in tern states `#import <React/RCTBridge.h>` and it is with the RCTBridge file that the header file not found is coming from.

I am using react native 0.40 and react-native-code-push 1.16.1-beta.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing the issue. Please let me know if you need any more info and I will gladly provide. I would like to mention that I do not believe this to be an issue with the libraries but rather my set up. I suspect this is just the first library that the compiler hits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is with the way RN 0.40 handles headers. React only knows about Release and Debug, so you have to add the Release headers path to your staging configuration and make sure React is built first as a dependency.

**Scheme:**

- Go to `Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes`.
- Double click your scheme. In my case I made a **staging** scheme and
  set build configuration to **Staging** in the **Run** section.
- Then in the **Build** section, make sure **Parallelize Build** is **off**
- Make sure the React build target is in the list of targets. If not,
  hit the **+** button, add it, and drag it to the top. Then hit **Close**.

**Target Dependencies:**

- Now select your target in the navigator, go to **Build Phases**, and
  under **Target Dependencies** add React. This ensures XCode builds React before the rest of the project.

**Header Path:**

- Select your target in the navigator, go to **Build Settings**.
- Click the **+**, add the user-defined setting `REACT_HEADERS_PATH` and set the value to `$(BUILD_DIR)/Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include`. It should resolve to something like `build/Release-iphoneos/include`
- Then still in **Build Settings**, scroll up to **Header Search Paths** and add `$(REACT_HEADERS_PATH)` to the list for the Staging configuration only.

Now Clean and Build...

I found this solution [here on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11813#issuecomment-273279257) after struggling for 2 days. All credit goes to the author of that comment.

Comment: How did I not see that post. I spent days trying to figure this out. You are amazing!!! Thanks so much!!!!!!!!! I had given up hope on this and was just using the release build config

Comment: I know your pain :) - in the end I went to the react native issues github page on github and entered  "staging" in the filter box

Answer (score 1):

The solution above did not work for me. This may help someone.

1. Open up your project in XCode.
2. Open up the Libraries folder.  You should see React.xcodeproj and several RCT*.xcodeproj.
3. Drag the React.xcodeproj into each of the other projects.
4. Click on each project and navigate to the Build Phases tab.
5. Click on Target Dependencies and add React as a target dependency